# Enabling SMB on user , won't work in 10.5 from Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, bash, terminal

I'm using this code in my Cocoa Application to enable SMB on USER account.

Same if you go-System Preferences-File Sharing-Options, end enable user.

It works fine on MAC OS X 10.6, and 10.7 .

**But on 10.5 it shows a log  "testUser is not a password server account."**

I have no idea what does this mean. But if you try the same thing from Terminal it works fine,

**pwpolicy -u testUser -sethashtypes SMB-NT on**

```
   char *command= "/usr/bin/pwpolicy";

    char *args1[] = {"-u","testUser","-sethashtypes","SMB-NT","on",nil};


    //execute dscl with args1 arguments
    err = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef,
                                             command,
                                             kAuthorizationFlagDefaults,
                                             args1,
                                             &pipe);
```

Any idea, what I can change, so it will work on 10.5 as well?

Answer (score 0):

This may not coming from enabling the Samba share code instead it may be a password setting issue. Try looking into: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1509269?start=0&tstart=0